# How to configure MySQL JDBC driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.12?

Tags: java, mysql, apache-flex, jdbc

I have downloaded MySQL JDBC driver from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/. How do I configure it?

Answer (score 6):

To the point, you just need to put it in the program's runtime classpath and then load it as follows:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
}
```

If you're using an IDE, then you need to add the library to the project's *Build Path*. If you're running it using `java.exe`, then you need to specify the full path to the JDBC driver JAR file in the `-cp` argument, e.g. (Windows-targeted):

```
java -cp .;/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar com.example.YourClass
```

For more information and hints check this [small MySQL+JDBC kickoff tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358).

**Update**: As per the comments, you're using Flex and you apparently want to interact with the DB at the server using Flex. Well, Flex runs at the client machine and Java + the DB runs at the server machine. Both are connected by network with HTTP as communication protocol. You need to write Java code on the server side accordingly (Servlet? Webservice?) which interacts with the DB based on the parameters/pathinfo given with the HTTP request and returns the desired results. Then you can just invoke HTTP requests from inside Flex and process the HTTP response.

Comment: but am using FLEX and JAVA.. SO WHATS THE WAY

Comment: Was it really necessary to yell? Cool down with all those caps, I've even sanitized your question from them to give you a chance to let your question survive here. Try to ask questions the smart way.

Comment: but am using flex and java..what to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more detail. You at least need to run a webserver which in turn runs a Java Servlet (e.g. Apache Tomcat) or a Java Webservice (e.g. Metro, Jersey, etc). You then put the MySQL JDBC driver over there and let it interact with the DB the usual JDBC way. The Servlet/Webservice should just listen on certain URL's and take actions accordingly based on request parameters/pathinfo.

Comment: as if now am using Tomcat as Java server.i just calling some methods using this ..now my need to connect MySql.but that zip file which i have downloaded from the http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ dont have any start up exe to install the Mysql.

Comment: It doesn't contain the MySQL DB server. It contains the MySQL JDBC driver. Please click the kickoff tutorial link provided in my answer to get a clear step-by-step instruction how to get Java+JDBC+MySQL to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the guidelines given at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing.html.
Also check the comments for more ideas and info. I.e: putting it in `[PATH_TO_JAVA]/jre/lib/ext/` (on Win Mashine) or `/Library/Java/Extensions` (Mac OS X) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Refer < http://www.developer.com/java/data/jdbc-and-mysql-installation-and-preparation-of-mysql.html> or

The JDBC .jar file needs to be added to the library, this can be done by adding it manually to '...jre\lib\ext' folder of your Java installation. It will be automatically included in the default library available to every project you create.