# MySql - No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to make a database connection but when i try to get the connection from my database it gives me the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://play.zsinfo.nl:3306/daansander
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at me.daansander.login.database.MySql.getConnection(MySql.java:28)
at me.daansander.login.database.Sql.connect(Sql.java:13)
at me.daansander.login.Login.main(Login.java:11)
```

i looked into the code and i found the line where the problem is:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db, user, pass);
```

but i could not find the problem i tried this on other plugins and it works just fine

Comment: Can you connect to that database from your machine using a regular MySQL client?

Comment: yes i can connect to my database from my machine using a regular MySQL client

Comment: Is the driver for MySQL on the classpath?

Comment: yes it is on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says that your class can not find the correct mysql connector library file. you can make sure it by writing a simple JDBC client class and run it on command line by specifying the path to your library.

you can find more from this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907141/how-to-configure-mysql-jdbc-driver-mysql-connector-java-5-1-12) and it will show you how to check the configuration properly. hope it will guide you!